Retrieving previous WhatsApp Backups from Google Drive
My phone went through a complete factory reset. I had backed my Whatsapp messages and media before this. As I reinstalled WhatsApp and tried restoring from my Drive automatically, the app glitched and only showed the groups I was part of. No Message or media was restored and my backup was replaced with just the group. Now I lost all my messages.
Is there any way I could access my previous WhatsApp Backup from Google Drive?
Like is there such a thing as version history or a recycle bin for backups
